# Configuring TFS to Work Like VSS

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

We're looking to migrate from Visual Source Safe 2005 to Team Foundation Server 2013. I've installed TFS 2013 in Basic Mode. I let it install SQL Server Express.

I want to set up a similar workflow to the one we currently have in VSS. We have a small team so I'd like to set up an exclusive checkout model, no branching and merging (I think this involves forcing server-side workspaces).

How can I do this at a collection level for all future projects?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against forcing a modern SCM to act like an inflexible, ancient one. If it's a small team, it shouldn't take them more than a few days to get used to using the tool correctly.

Comment: Agree with Daniel, and I believe you will benefit a lot via with the TFS system. By the way, do you get any difficulties when you're working with TFS? Please check my reply below specially address two points you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To disable multiple check-out, please go to team -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control -> uncheck the Enable multiple check-out option.

[image]

2. If you indeed don't want to work with branch-merge feature, you can disable the corresponding branch-merge permissions for your team members. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx#VersionControl By the way, branch-merge also works on local workspace.

Comment: So that looks like how you'd do it on a project level. How do I set this at the Collection or Application Tier level? Because this looks like I'd have to set this for each SLN...

Comment: The first setting in my reply:"disable multiple check-out" is on team project level; the second setting :"disable merge & branch" permissions can be set on team project level as well. That's, if these two settings are configured on team project level, all solutions (.sln) under that team project can't be checked out by multiple users at the same time; and can't be branched and merged either. You don't need to set the settings for all SLN.

Comment: Ok, but I'm new to TFS: Do all SLNs in your repo go under one Team Project, or is more like one SLN to one project typically? For instance, your corporate intranet and your employee self service websites would not both go under the same team project, would they?